# Sonar analysed projects not shown

Tags: maven, sonarqube, build-server

I've got a Sonar server (v3.5), configured, running, etc. I've also got a project built with Maven (3.0.3) and analyzed with this Sonar instance. A strange thing is: the "All projects" view displays "No data", however the "Bulk deletion" page lists the project. Also: the project id is stored in the projects table of the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: On the "Bulk deletion" page, on which tab do you see your project? On the "Ghosts" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was related to the user authorization: only one user had the access to the newly created projects. It's a useful setting to have the "Anyone" special group assigned to the newly created projects as "User" and "Code viewer".

Comment: Where do you assign this?